# Incorrect syntax near ')'. when trying to insert values into the database

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm new and this is my first question.

I'm trying to insert a value into the database and I get the error message

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` gets highlighted. Here's my code:

```
con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO orders ('" + IDProduct.Text + "')", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, **NEVER**, **NEVER**  **NEVER** build sql queries like this. Use parameterized queries instead.

Secondly, you're missing "VALUES" in your sql command.

```
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ( .... )
```

**edit:**

Thirdly, as marc_s suggests, it's a good idea to specify column names as well. That way you can avoid some surprises later.

Comment: Plus, I would add: **always** specify an explicit column list in your `INSERT` statement: `INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(Col1, Col2, Col3, ....) VALUES(VAl1, Val2, Val3, .....)`

Comment: @marc_s, good point, thanks. Added that to my answer as well.

Comment: @user1477362 Welcome to [so] - there is a holo CheckBox next to each answer, tick it will give you a couple of points. Just an FYI guys, you CAN omit the VALUES and Column names which could have been the cause for confusion. Like this: `INSERT INTO ORDERS  (SELECT '" + IDProduct.Text + "')"`

Comment: Jeremy, yes - however, code like that is both extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks (because the value of `IDProduct.Text` could be `";DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE 1 = 1;;"`) and - if the schema changes, your select statement suddenly doesn't work anymore (because the order of columns in Orders now doesn't reflect the order specified in `IDProduct.Text`). This is a clear-cut case where Parameterized Queries are a necessity.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the SQL statement INSERT INTO has two forms

You don't specifiy the column names

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

or you specify both the column names and the values

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3,...)
             VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

The first case should be used when all the fields values are specified.
The second case should be used when you want to insert the values for specific columns

Answer (score 1):

Values should be used:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert query syntax is:

```
insert into <tablename> values(col1 <datatype>,col2 <datatype>)
```

you missed `values` that's why you get error modify this line:

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO orders values ('" + IDProduct.Text + "')", con)
```

Comment: I think the correct insert query syntax is `insert into <tablename> (col1,col2) VALUES (@col1,@col2)`?